# Selecting the last element among various nested containers

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I select the last and deepest element in CSS?

Is there a way to improve this css code?

What solution do you proposed for a deep tree? (~15-25).

I'm avoiding using javascript. But SASS solutions are welcome.(maybe using  @for?)

```css
/*level 1*/

div.case > ul:last-child > li.leaf:last-child > div {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: red;
}
/*level 2*/

div.case > ul:last-child > li.expanded:last-child > ul > li.leaf:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: blue;
}
/*level 3*/

div.case > ul:last-child > li.expanded:last-child > ul > li.expanded:last-child > ul > li.leaf:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: green;
}
/*level 4*/

div.case > ul:last-child > li.expanded:last-child > ul > li.expanded:last-child > ul > li.expanded:last-child > ul > li.leaf:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="case">
  <h1>Case 0</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="expanded">
      <div>1. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>1. content</div>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>2. content</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded">
      <div>2. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>1. content</div>
          <ul>
            <li class="leaf">
              <div>1. content</div>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf">
              <div>2. content</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf">
      <div>3. content (bold)</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="case">
  <h1>Case 1</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="expanded">
      <div>1. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>1. content</div>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>2. content</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded">
      <div>2. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>1. content</div>
          <ul>
            <li class="leaf">
              <div>1. content</div>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf">
              <div>2. content</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded">
      <div>3. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>1. content</div>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>2. content</div>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>3. content (bold)</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="case">
  <h1>Case 2</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="expanded">
      <div>1. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>1. content</div>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>2. content</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf">
      <div>2. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>1. content</div>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>2. content</div>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>3. content</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded">
      <div>3. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="expanded">
          <div>1. content a</div>
          <ul>
            <li class="leaf">
              <div>1. content</div>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf">
              <div>2. content (bold)</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="case">
  <h1>Case 3</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="expanded">
      <div>1. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>1. content</div>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>2. content</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded">
      <div>2. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>1. content</div>
          <ul>
            <li class="leaf">
              <div>1. content</div>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf">
              <div>2. content</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded">
      <div>3. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="expanded">
          <div>2. content</div>
          <ul>
            <li class="expanded">
              <div>1. content</div>
              <ul>
                <li class="leaf">
                  <div>1. content</div>
                </li>
                <li class="leaf">
                  <div>2. content (bold)</div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="case">
  <h1>Case 4</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="expanded">
      <div>1. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>1. content</div>
        </li>
        <li class="leaf">
          <div>2. content</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded">
      <div>2. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="expanded">
          <div>2. content</div>
          <ul>
            <li class="expanded">
              <div>1. content</div>
              <ul>
                <li class="leaf">
                  <div>1. content</div>
                </li>
                <li class="leaf">
                  <div>2. content</div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="expanded">
      <div>3. content</div>
      <ul>
        <li class="expanded">
          <div>1. content</div>
          <ul>
            <li class="leaf">
              <div>1. content</div>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf">
              <div>2. content(bold)</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="case">
  <h1>Case 5</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="leaf">
      <div>content 1</div>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf">
      <div>content 2</div>
    </li>
    <li class="leaf">
      <div>content 3(bold)</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If possible i would look at adding a class to identify depth on your `ul` tags along the line of  `<ul class='depth0'>`

Comment: it's possible but it's not preferable.

Comment: I don't understand, is there a problem with your code?  There's no magic shortcut for this, you have to write out as much code as you think you have to.

Comment: I just want to know if anyone knows a better way to achieve the same result.

Comment: As you said you might be able to make this easier for you by using sass' control directives.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to target the last `li` tag in multiple `ul`s, where the number of nesting levels in the `ul`s is unpredictable.

You want a selector that targets the "last and deepest element" in a containing block where the number of elements preceding it in the block are unknown and irrelevant.

This doesn't appear to be possible with [**Selectors 2.1**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html) or [**Selectors 3**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

The `:last-child`, `:last-of-type` and `nth-child` pseudo-classes work when the nesting levels are fixed. In a dynamic environment where there are multiple lists of varying nesting levels these selector rules will break.

This will select the last `li` in the first level `ul`:

```
div.case > ul > li:last-child
```

This will select the last `li` in the second level `ul`:

```
div.case > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child
```

This will select the last `li` in the third level `ul`:

```
div.case > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child > ul > li:last-child
```

and so on...

A solution, however, may exist in [**Selectors 4**](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview), which browsers haven't yet implemented:

```
li:last-child:not(:has(> li))
```

This rule targets last child `li`s that have no descendant `li`s, which matches your requirement.

For now, however, if you know the nesting level for each of your `ul` containers you can apply a class to each targeted `li`.

*<sup>Thanks @BoltClock for help crafting the Selectors 4 rule (see comments).</sup>*

Comment: It's not being addressed in Selectors 4. The name :nth-match() is misleading - it's supposed to function similarly to :nth-child(), and in fact the latest ED reflects that.

Comment: I wasn't referring to nth-* in CSS4. I was referring more toward something like `li:last-child:not($li li) { }`, which basically says (I think) don't target a last child `li` that has any `li` descendants.

Comment: Ah, you are right. That'll be `li:last-child:not(:has(> li))` in the ED, but it actually does what the OP wants.