# Css selector for last ul inside unknown level ul

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to select only the last child ul as underlined in the picture

[image]

Code

```css
li:before {
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>Abc !</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Def !</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>456</li>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Ghi !</li>
                    <li>Jkl !</li>
                    <li>Mno !</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>789</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <ul>
                        <li>Prs !</li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>1011</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us your relevant code, and what you have tried. Also be more specific for what do you want.

Comment: Can you give class to that particular ul element and access it using that?

Comment: @Monika
This is part of a dynamic menu. So I can't add a class for every last ul element.

Comment: @GheorgeMihai What does __dynamic__ mean in this context? Is it created with an backend scripting language (like PHP, Python, etc.)? Or is it dynamically created/changed in the Frontend with JavaScript?

Comment: May be this could help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599805/selecting-the-last-element-among-various-nested-containers

Comment: @yunzen it's created with PHP.

Comment: @GheorgeMihai Can't you dynamically add the classed to the relevant `<ul>`s in PHP?

Comment: Currently, there's no way to do it with plain CSS (possible with JS). With the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) CSS pseudo-class, it will be possible, but there's no browser support for it.

Comment: Check this: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/ac825f789eb846c61ae5f9cbd2529896

Comment: Usually being dynamic means it's *easier* to add classes to every element, not harder...

Comment: @yunzen selecting one element or many elements doesn't make this question *not* a duplicate. As a side note the duplicate target have one level but it can work with any level so the selector proposed there will work here too. You answer like the most upvoted one is using the same selector in the duplicate target.

Comment: @yunzen Please don't add code to a question where OP just posted a screenshot. Such a question should be closed as off-topic until the *asker* puts in the minimum required effort. Also, it's OP's prerogative to describe how the duplicate targets don't solve the question, not yours.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly this can't be achieved dynamically with CSS. However this can be achieved with jQuery by filtering every ul that does not have a ul descendent.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul').filter(":not(:has(ul))").addClass('last');
});
```

```css
.last {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    level 1
    <ul>
      <li>level 2</li>
      <li>level 2</li>
      <li>level 2</li>
      <li>
        level 2
        <ul>
          <li>level 3</li>
          <li>level 3</li>
          <li>
            level 3
            <ul>
              <li>level 4</li>
              <li>level 4</li>
              <li>level 4</li>
              <li>level 4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>level 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>level 1</li>
  <li>
    level 1
    <ul>
      <li>level 2</li>
      <li>level 2</li>
      <li>level 2</li>
      <li>level 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>level 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you need to use `.filter()`? Could it just be written as `$('ul:not(:has(ul))')`?

Comment: @sean Yes you are correct. That would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible pure CSS method that would do this.

#### Edit

With CSS Selector Level 4 it would be easy: `ul:not(:has(ul))`
You can do it with jQuery, which supports the `:has()` selector.

`jQuery('ul:not(:has(ul))').addClass('deep')`

Here is a VanillaJS solution:

```js
"use strict";
console.clear()

{
  const container = document.getElementById('container')
  
  // Get all list items inside #container
  let uls = Array.from(container.getElementsByTagName('ul'));
  
  uls = uls.filter(ul => {
    return ul.getElementsByTagName('ul').length === 0
  })
  
  // Add a class to those list items
  uls.forEach(ul => ul.classList.add('deep'))
  
}
```

```css
.deep {
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

li:before {
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>Abc !</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Def !</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>456</li>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Ghi !</li>
                    <li>Jkl !</li>
                    <li>Mno !</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>789</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <ul>
                        <li>Prs !</li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>1011</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

The following is an incorrect answer, because I misread the OP
You can do with a little JavaScript:

```js
"use strict";
console.clear()

{
  const container = document.getElementById('container')
  
  // Get all list items inside #container
  let lis = Array.from(container.getElementsByTagName('li'));

  // Filter to get only those, that don't have child lists
  lis = lis.filter(el => {
    return el.querySelectorAll(':scope > ul').length === 0
  })
  // Filter again to get only those, that are last childs
  lis = lis.filter(el => {
    return el.parentElement.lastElementChild === el
  })
  
  // Add a class to those list items
  lis.forEach(el => el.parentElement.classList.add('deep'))
  
}
```

```css
.deep {
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

li:before {
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>123</li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>Abc !</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Def !</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>456</li>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <ul>
                    <li>Ghi !</li>
                    <li>Jkl !</li>
                    <li>Mno !</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <ul>
                        <li>Prs !</li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try this.
Thanks

Comment: @GeorgeMihai I updated my answer. The first version made false acclaims and yielded false results.