# How to scrape older html with nested tables in R?

Tags: r, rvest

I'm struggling to scrape an older html file (hundreds actually) that does not have css, so css selection doesn't work.

Example page: http://home.business.utah.edu/u0982704/ipeds/gr2002.html

I need to get all the info that is in bordered tables, though I'll also need certain other elements such as the variable code after each horizontal rule (ie "CHRTSTAT-1919-Graduation rate status in cohort") in order to attach that to the bordered table info below it.

[image]

I'd like to end up with something like this:

[image]

The file contains all text within a table, and then has tables within tables.  I am unsure of how to use `html_nodes()` and `html_table()` to get a clear result.  Using html_table gives me a massive list of lists of lists, and there is no obvious way I"m seeing to flatten it out in a useful way.

One thing I've tried: using `html_text()` and then `read_table()` gets me most of the way there, but the actual bordered tables on the page don't parse due to the fact that there are no line returns - these seem to be the deepest nested tables.  So if I could identify these and parse them using some other method, that might work.

Currently using `rvest` but open to other packages.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(rvest))

xh <- read_html("http://home.business.utah.edu/u0982704/ipeds/gr2002.html")

htable <- xh %>% 
  html_table(fill = T)

htext <- xh %>% 
  html_nodes("table") %>% 
  html_text(xh)

text_table <- read_table(htext) #This gets me most of the way there, but the tables from the page (ie the "Value Label", "Code Value", "Frequency", "Percentage" gets smashed because there are no line returns since it is seperate table rows)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

EDIT: I just noticed that my read_table method seems to not get all the data from the table:

`text_table %>% slice(15) %>% pull` only has part of the table:

`[1] "4-year institutions total12,0104.74%4-year institutions, Adjusted cohort (revised cohort minus exclusions)22,0104.74%4-year institutions, Completers within 150% of normal time31,9804.67%4-year institutions, Tranfer-out students47671.81%4-year institutions, Still enrolled in long programs5950.22%Bachelor's or equiv subcohort (4-yr institution)61,8464.35%Bachelor's or equiv subcohort (4-yr institution) adjusted cohort (revised cohort minus exclusions)81,8464.35%Bachelor's or equiv subcohort (4-yr institution) Completers within 150% of normal time total91,8204.29%Bachelor's or equiv subcohort (4-yr institution) Completers of programs of < 2 yrs (150% of normal time)10920.22%Bachelor's or equiv subcohort (4-yr institution) Completers of programs of 2 but <4 yrs (150% of normal time)114020.95%Bachelor's or equiv"`

Comment: If the relevant tables are, as you write, the "deepest nested tables", perhaps this might aid you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31599805/selecting-the-last-element-among-various-nested-containers - ?